# Referencing $HOME or ~ in Info.plist

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I need to set an environment variable for my application when it is started from the Finder. It is the location of a directory. The path is relative to $HOME. I am using the Info.plist file to set this environment variable. However, I cannot get it to take $HOME or ~. Can this be done?

i.e. I want something like this:

MYAPPDIR=~/myappname

Yes, I am using the .plist editor. It does work, i.e. my app finds it if I hardcode the full path like this:

MYAPPDIR=/Users/myname/myappname

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do that? If you really want to set the environment variable in your app, do this:

```
 NSString* expanded=[@"~/myappname" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
 setenv("MYAPPDIR",[expanded UTF8String],1);
```

please disregard the following rants if you really wanted to set the environment variable.

---

However, **never force a user to put your app in a certain directory.**

In addition, **never save a file in a user-visible non-user-configurable place**.

In OS X, applications are made into `.app` bundles so that a user can freely move it.

If you need to get the app's current position, just use

```
NSString*appPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

If you'd like to save a big file somewhere, create a directory inside `~/Library/Application Support/` called

```
~/Library/Application Support/yourappname/
```

and save files inside. If you just need to save a few data, use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It automatically saves the data to

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.yourcompany.yourapp.plist
```

and re-loads the content when the app is launched again. Just do

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"boo" forKey:@"bar"];
```

and retrieve, after your app's relaunched, using

```
NSString* boo=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"bar"];
```

etc.

Comment: I appreciate the rants. I am a Mac novice and am glad to have the advice.